# Get request encoding in Servlet / Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, character-encoding

I need to get the actual character encoding on an HTTP requests.

I can use `HttpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()`, but this returns `null` when the encoding is not specified in the request. I can assume it to be `ISO-8859-1` then, [according to the FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1) and the HTTP specification.

Still I'd rather call a method which simply tells me what it is, rather than assuming things based on a spec. Is there such a method?

Answer (score 1):

When somebody is sending a request then it is his/her responsibility to set the right encoding for their request and if s/he doesn't then it should be safely treated as garbage. Speculating about the request encoding on the server side is not a wise thing to do as this would lead to unintended issues later. It is better to fail a request than to assume things on your own. Also, fail the request as early as possible as unnecessary processing will consume resources and may prove a potential exploit if not guarded well.

Comment: Whether it's safe or not, Tomcat handles the request (to get POST parameters as strings). To do that, it needs to use an encoding. I simply want to know which one that is.

Answer (score 0):

If the encoding isn't specified in the http packet, then this function will have trouble, its copped a lot of criticism for a while.

Apparently calling it early on in your doPost method is more useful, but i don't bother, I go straight for Spring's CharacterEncodingFilter:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html

Its a bit more work but it makes life easier in the long run.

---

There is no simple method to check this. But once you get the body of the request, you could try creating a string out of it and catch encoding exception to determine the encoding. But I don't think this is elegant.

---

Here is another good article on checking the validity of requests before processing:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest

Comment: What kind of trouble does `getCharacterEncoding()` have, other than the mentioned returning of `null`?

Comment: None, just that is always returns null.

Comment: Even if the encoding is specified in the `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get it if it's not present in the request header.

It's however the same encoding as **you** have used in the response of the HTML page which presents the POST form. Normally, such a HTML page is served by a JSP for which the default response encoding is indeed ISO-8859-1, but is overrideable by

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

This will set the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8` response header which in turn will instruct the webbrowser to encode any submitted form data using the very same charset. To properly process the POST request body using this encoding, you should be explicitly calling

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

beforehand when `getCharacterEncoding()` returns `null`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Useful information, but unfortunately in my specific case I have no control over the encoding of the form. This is because there is no form; I'm dealing with a PayPal IPN request.

Comment: @Bart: You should have mentioned that in the beginning... Paypal IPN uses Windows CP1252 encoding (a terrible choice, I know), so `request.setCharacterEncoding("CP1252")` should do.

Comment: I figured that out, but I was looking for a generic way to always get the encoding right.

Comment: That's answered in the 1st paragraph of my answer. There exist several "character encoding detectors" but they are far from 100% reliable.